# MySQL view doesn't update when underlaying table changes across different users

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've searched and I can't seem to find anything.

Here is the situation:

- t1 = table 1
- t2 = table 2
- v = view of table 1 and table 2 joined

1.) User 1 is logged into database. Does `SELECT * FROM v`;

2.) User 2 is logged into same database and does `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 2, 3)`;

3.) User 1 does another `SELECT * FROM v;` User 1 can't see the inserted row from User 2 until logging out and logging back in.

Seems like views don't get sync'd across "sessions"? How can I make it so User 1 can see the INSERT?

FYI I'm using python and mysqldb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of logging out and logging back in, user 2 could simply commit their transaction.

MySQL InnoDB tables use transactions, requiring a BEGIN before one or more SQL statements, and either COMMIT or ROLLBACK afterwards, resulting in all your updates/inserts/deletes either happening or not. But there's a "feature" that results in an automatic BEGIN if not explicitly issued, and an automatic COMMIT when the connection is closed. This is why you see the changes after the other user closes the connection.

You should really get into the habit of explicitly beginning and committing your transactions, but there's also another way: set connection.autocommit = True, which will result in every sql update/insert/delete being wrapped in its own implicit transaction, resulting in the behavior you originally expected.

Don't take what I said above to be entirely factually correct, but it suffices to explain the fundamentals of what's going on and how to control it.

Comment: Running `COMMIT` seems to work, I'm going to mark this as the answer but could you explain why I have to do this?

Comment: Ok, let me know if my explanation suffices.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out autocommit is enabled in mysql configuration but "Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default, as required by the DB-API standard (PEP-249)."

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to using the MySQL UPDATE command?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of `UPDATE v` where v is your view of the table.

Comment: `UPDATE v` gives invalid syntax.